# Errors in symbol variables

Tags: android

[This is my mapsactivity.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgymr.png)

I am unable to resolve the following errors :
(1)cannot find symbol variable show_distance_time
(2)cannot find symbol variable btnDriving
(3)cannot find symbol variable btnWalk

Comment: please share your code..

Comment: please set this id in your respective xml

Comment: have you add `show_distance_time` as id for TextView?

Comment: Thank you i resolve the error

Comment: When i run my project am getting an error of FATAL EXCEPTION : MAIN and when i click on driving mode or walking mode button then unfortunately the project was stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define Views with proper IDs in your respective xml file for MapsActivity & then try to clean & rebuild the project.